# 100% Height with fluid layouts?

Tags: html, css, height, fluid-layout, sticky-footer

I am a beginner at coding and I am looking for a way to implement a 100% height on my main container DIV to fill up my full web page page, as well as get a sticky footer at the bottom.

I would like it to display properly as a full web page with a sticky footer.

I Have been looking all over the place for a nice clean explanation and I would like to have an easy way for myself and others to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="BSHome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div class="fluid maincontainer">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid">Burning Man Sonata Picture</div>
  <div class="Navgationbar">Navigation Bar</div>
  <div class="fluid MissionStatement"><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="fluid youtube">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="fluid footer">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "footer"</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from       the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}

/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     4;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    12;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

.fluid {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 86.45%;
    padding-left: 2.275%;
    padding-right: 2.275%;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.Navgationbar {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.MissionStatement {
    background-color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 90%;
}
.maincontainer {
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #333333;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/bg-01.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #000 url(Images/playa.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    /**for Safari,Chrome**/
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    /**for Firefox**/
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    /**for Opera**/
    -o-background-size: cover;
    /**for other browsers**/
    background-size: cover;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}

.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.youtube {
    width: 100%;
}
.zeroMargin_mobile {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
display: none;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 90.675%;
    padding-left: 1.1625%;
    padding-right: 1.1625%;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#div1 {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
}

body {
background: #000 url(Images/playa.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
/**for Safari,Chrome**/
-webkit-background-size: cover;
/**for Firefox**/
  -moz-background-size: cover;
/**for Opera**/
-o-background-size: cover;
/**for other browsers**/
background-size: cover;
}

.Navgationbar {
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.MissionStatement {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
}

.maincontainer {
width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
}

.youtube {
    width: 45%;
}

.hide_tablet {
display: none;
}

.zeroMargin_tablet {
margin-left: 0;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 88.5%;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    clear: none;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#div1 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
}

body {
    background: #000 url(Images/playa.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    /**for Safari,Chrome**/
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    /**for Firefox**/
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    /**for Opera**/
    -o-background-size: cover;
    /**for other browsers**/
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 0%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.Navgationbar {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-family: serif;
}

.MissionStatement {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 98%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.maincontainer {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    bottom: 100px;
}

.footer {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #330066;
    position: static;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.youtube {
    width: 45%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.zeroMargin_desktop {
margin-left: 0;
}

.hide_desktop {
display: none;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would have website on a full height you must use this:

```
html, body{height:100%;}
```

for a sticky footer you must use:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.content{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -150px; 
}
.content:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
footer, .content:after{
  height: 142px; 
}
```

and html

```
<div class="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: This will push the first 150px of the content off of the page. Its better to set the height of content to a calc, webkit calc, and moz calc with the calc (100% - 142px ).

Comment: calc has some potential support issues, IE9 and Android browser, http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

The above method works by taking 150px off the bottom,
http://jsbin.com/simeza/3/